# Populate google line chart by calling angularjs controller function from javascript code

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I have created a static google line chart:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
   google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

   function drawChart() {
.      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Year', 'Massachusetts', 'National'],
          ['2010',  70,  76],
          ['2011',  89,  82],
          ['2012',  96,  86],
          ['2013',  100,  91],
          ['2014',  null,  94],
          ['2015',  null,  98],
          ['2016',  100,  99],
          ['2017',  124,  100],
          ['2018',  125,  102]
       ]);

       var options = {
            title: 'Average Home Insurance Premium',
            curveType: 'function',
            legend: { position: 'bottom' },
            subtitle: 'in dollars (USD)',
            vAxis: {
                viewWindow: {
                    min: 0
                }
            },
            width: 250,
            height: 200,
            sliceVisibilityThreshold: 0,
            interpolateNulls:true
       };

       var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('fsm_container'));

       chart.draw(data, options);
    }
```

I have created a API to get data to create dynamic line chart and created a function in angularjs controller function.

```
$scope.getChartData = function () {
    debugger;
    $http.post('/Home/LineChartData?ZIP_CODE=' + '02111' + '&Lob=Homeowners').then(function (response) {
        if (response.status == 200) {
            var Jsondata = JSON.parse(response.data);
            }
        }
    });
};
```

I want to pass the Jsondata (in the above function) to the chart and display it there.
Is there any way to call that function from the code that is used to create chart?

Answer (score 0):

I have used another method. I used ajax call and directly hit my cs controller functuin from here instead of calling angularjs function.

```
$.ajax({
            url: "LineChartData?ZIP_CODE=" + getUrlVars()["cal"] + "&Lob=Homeowners",
            dataType: "json",
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {}
});
```